# List<object> Self-Filter

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list like

```
 List<VoieData> listVoieData = new List<VoieData>();
```

and in VoieData Class I have :

```
public class VoieData
{
    public int Depart { set; get; }
    public int Arrive { set; get; }
    public int DistanceDepart { set; get; }
    public int DistanceArrive { set; get; }
}
```

Since I have a massive values I want to only consider all my `Depart` number ,  I would like to filter the `listVoieData` by finding the `Arrive` only have the same value as the 
`Depart`

for example I have

```
listVoieData.Select(p=>p.Depart).ToList()= List<int>{1,2,3};
listVoieData.Select(p=>p.Arrive).ToList()= List<int>{1,2,3,4,5};
```

I need to throw away  the entire `VoieData` which contain {4,5} as `Arrive`

right now my soulution is like this , but it' s not correct ;

```
List<VoieData> listVoieDataFilter = listVoieData .Join(listVoieData , o1 => o1.Arrive, o2 => o2.Depart, (o1, o2) => o1).ToList();
```

Sorry for the confusing question ; 
  I want to remove Arrive which is different from all the Depart in the list list , and return the new 
    List

it 's not only in one `VoieData`;

```
Arrive!=Depart
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to remove all `voieData` where `Arrive!=Depart`, or all those where `Arrive` is different from **all** the `Depart` of **all** `voieData`?

Comment: We need to see what you put in `listVoieData` to start with for your example output to mean anything to us.  Output without input isn't very helpful.

Comment: @JuliánUrbano  Yes I want to remove Arrive which is different from all the Depart

Comment: Thanks Everybody ; @JuliánUrbano gave me the answer I want .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to remove all objects where `Arrive` is not in **any** of the `Depart` from **any** object. In that case, first get all `Depart` and then filter by `Arrive`:

```
HashSet<int> allDepart = new HashSet<int>(listVoieData.Select(x => x.Depart));
var result = listVoieData.Where(v => !allDepart.Contains(v.Arrive))
```

We use a `HashSet<int>` for efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

That would be a typical case to use linq.

something like:

```
var res = from data in listVoieData
          where data.Depart == data.Arrive
          select data;
```

and then optionally just use `res.ToArray()` to run the query and get the array.

Answer (score 1):

Use LINQ `Where`:

```
var records = listVoieData.Where(x => x.Arrive == x.Depart);
```

This will return results where both `Arrive` and `Depart` are the same.

Answer (score -1):

Since you've stated that you want:

> I want to remove Arrive which is different from all the Depart

This can be re-phrased as, "The set of all arrivals except those in the set of departures", which translates very nicely into the following LINQ query:

```
var arrivalsWithNoDepartures = listVoieData.Select(p=>p.Arrive)
    .Except(listVoieData.Select(p=>p.Depart));
```